# Spring Webflux consumer is reactive but producer is not (some external service)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux

I'm going thru lot of documentations and POCs of Spring Webflux and little new to this, (I have worked on Spring MVC earlier) to understand the concepts. One of the scenario I'm exploring for implementing webflux is as mentioned in title.

If there is some third-party REST service which is consumed by my micro-service and it gives me lot of data without using pagination. So even if my micro-service is developed with Webflux will it handle the back-pressure ?

Since the external REST service may not respond in streams or developed using reactive framework. Would it impact anyway on my service ?

It would be great help if someone can throw some light on this area or guide me to some relevant documentation/implementation.

Thanks in advance.